# Split NumPy array by list of indices

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to get the mean of each subgroup of the data, grouped by a list of indices. I may have failed to explain it properly, but the sample code below should point out clearly what I want to do.

```py
import numpy as np
means = [data[i].mean(axis=0) for i in indices]

# data.shape = (17 492, 3 650)
# data.dtype = float64
# indices.shape = (30, 17 492)
# indices.dtype = bool
```

Here, `data` is an `N * M` array of floats and `indices` is an `L * N` array of boolean masks. Each `L` of indices is a boolean mask indicating the `l`'th group of data to be averaged together.

Depending on data size, this is the most intensive part of my process. If there is a way to do this purely with NumPy functions, I'd like to refactor it.

Comment: The challenge is the `data[i]` will have shape (n,3650), where `n` varies.  If `L` is small relative to other dimensions (here it is only 30), your iteration might be as fast as anything that tries to build a more complex array structure (higher dim, or masked).  My 'rule-of-thumb' is that `a (relatively) few iterations on a complex task, is often faster than the whole-array equivalent`.  The iterations take up time, but the whole-array version has more complex memory processing, which also consumes time.

Comment: The case here is `L=30`, but it can reach ~1 000, potentially much more when I start combining multiple data arrays later on

Answer (score 2):

A smaller sample:

```
In [261]: data = np.arange(100).reshape(20,5)
In [262]: indices =  np.random.rand(10,20)>.5
```

Your list comprehension:

```
In [263]: means = [data[i].mean(axis=0) for i in indices]
In [264]: np.array(means)
Out[264]: 
array([[24.        , 25.        , 26.        , 27.        , 28.        ],
       [50.45454545, 51.45454545, 52.45454545, 53.45454545, 54.45454545],
       [35.55555556, 36.55555556, 37.55555556, 38.55555556, 39.55555556],
       [50.625     , 51.625     , 52.625     , 53.625     , 54.625     ],
       [60.        , 61.        , 62.        , 63.        , 64.        ],
       [53.33333333, 54.33333333, 55.33333333, 56.33333333, 57.33333333],
       [41.875     , 42.875     , 43.875     , 44.875     , 45.875     ],
       [59.375     , 60.375     , 61.375     , 62.375     , 63.375     ],
       [33.125     , 34.125     , 35.125     , 36.125     , 37.125     ],
       [54.5       , 55.5       , 56.5       , 57.5       , 58.5       ]])
```

A whole-array approach, creating a larger array with `nan` for the masked-out values.  There's a whole set of `np.nan...` functions that strip out `nan` from float arrays, and do calculations without them.

```
In [265]: res = np.zeros((10,20,5))
In [266]: res[:] = data
In [267]: res[~indices]=np.nan
In [268]: mean2 =np.nanmean(res, axis=1)
In [269]: mean2
Out[269]: 
array([[24.        , 25.        , 26.        , 27.        , 28.        ],
       [50.45454545, 51.45454545, 52.45454545, 53.45454545, 54.45454545],
       [35.55555556, 36.55555556, 37.55555556, 38.55555556, 39.55555556],
       [50.625     , 51.625     , 52.625     , 53.625     , 54.625     ],
       [60.        , 61.        , 62.        , 63.        , 64.        ],
       [53.33333333, 54.33333333, 55.33333333, 56.33333333, 57.33333333],
       [41.875     , 42.875     , 43.875     , 44.875     , 45.875     ],
       [59.375     , 60.375     , 61.375     , 62.375     , 63.375     ],
       [33.125     , 34.125     , 35.125     , 36.125     , 37.125     ],
       [54.5       , 55.5       , 56.5       , 57.5       , 58.5       ]])
```

Values match; I don't know about timings.  What I get with this example might not apply to your much larger case.

Looking at the `nanmean` code, I figured out a more direct way of this:

```
In [286]: cnt = np.sum(indices, axis=1)
In [287]: x = (data*indices[:,:,None]).sum(axis=1)
In [288]: x/cnt[:,None]
Out[288]: 
array([[24.        , 25.        , 26.        , 27.        , 28.        ],
       [50.45454545, 51.45454545, 52.45454545, 53.45454545, 54.45454545],
       [35.55555556, 36.55555556, 37.55555556, 38.55555556, 39.55555556],
       [50.625     , 51.625     , 52.625     , 53.625     , 54.625     ],
       [60.        , 61.        , 62.        , 63.        , 64.        ],
       [53.33333333, 54.33333333, 55.33333333, 56.33333333, 57.33333333],
       [41.875     , 42.875     , 43.875     , 44.875     , 45.875     ],
       [59.375     , 60.375     , 61.375     , 62.375     , 63.375     ],
       [33.125     , 34.125     , 35.125     , 36.125     , 37.125     ],
       [54.5       , 55.5       , 56.5       , 57.5       , 58.5       ]])
```

Comment: Exactly what I want, but I have a feeling it's going to be memory hungry. I'll give it a try soon

Comment: So, yeah, this is what I'm looking for indeed, but the Python process goes from ~270 MB to ~17 GB of memory usage, which is quite extreme, to say the least. As I will be using this on data with shapes of more than `(250 000, 3 650)`, this won't work for me

Comment: Yes, expansion followed by contraction is a common `numpy` method, making a (L,N,M) intermediate array before contracting it to (L,M).  (L*N*M*8) is a good estimate of its size.  That's a big part of why the iteration approach can be better.  The only alternative is move the iteration to compiled code with something like `numba`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to do this?

```
import numpy as np

# Create a masked arraybased on the data and indices
masked_data = np.ma.masked_array(data, ~indices)

means = np.mean(masked_data, axis=0)
```

Comment: `data` is (N,M), `indices` is (L,N); those aren't compatible shapes.  The OP wants `L` means.